# if some checkboxes are 'checked' then check all javascript

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox, checkboxlist

```js
<!--

if all checkboxes are not 'checkecd' then check all
if some are 'checked' then check all
if all are 'checked' then uncheck all
-->

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
        btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            const allboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
            allboxes.forEach(box => {
                if(!box.checked){
                    box.checked = true;
                } else {
                    box.checked = false;
                }
            })
        })
```

```html
<button>select all</button>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
```

my code is not working as desire after clicking on button select all do..
if all checkboxes are not 'checkecd' then check all
if some are 'checked' then check all
if all are 'checked' then uncheck all

Comment: This two means same `if all checkboxes are not 'checkecd' then check all if some are 'checked' then check all`

Comment: on clicking button "select all" do 
if all checkboxes are  'uncheckecd' then check all
if some are 'checked' and some are unchecked then check all
if all are 'checked' then uncheck all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check all checkboxes with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493089/check-all-checkboxes-with-javascript)

Comment: And [How to check if all checkboxes are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14800954/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array `some` & `every`. Use `some` to check if some of the elements are checked and `every` to check if all are checked. Then accordingly check or uncheck

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const allboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  // if some of the checkbox is checked
  const isSomeCheck = [...allboxes].some(item => item.checked);
  // if all are checked
  const isAllChecked = [...allboxes].every(item => item.checked);
  // if some are checked then on click of button check all
  if (isSomeCheck) {
    allboxes.forEach(item => item.checked = true)
  }
  // if all are checked then uncheck all
  if (isAllChecked && isSomeCheck) {
    allboxes.forEach(item => item.checked = false)
  }
})
```

```html
<button>select all</button>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: All you need to check is if all are checked; if they are, then uncheck them all. Otherwise, check them all.

Answer (score 1):

Good old `querySelectorAll` with CSS pseudo class `:checked` to the rescue. You could shorten this up even further by moving the `length` comparison into the `forEach`.

```js
/*
if all checkboxes are not 'checkecd'
then check all
if some are 'checked'
then check all
if all are 'checked'
then uncheck all
*/

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const allboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  const checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  const allChecked = allboxes.length === checkedBoxes.length;
  allboxes.forEach(box => box.checked = !allChecked);
})
```

```html
<button>select all</button>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).
For example like this:

```js
if (Array.prototype.every.call(allboxes, box => !box.checked)) {
    allboxes.forEach(box => box.checked = true);
} else if (Array.prototype.every.call(allboxes, box => box.checked)) {
    allboxes.forEach(box => box.checked = false);
} else if (Array.prototype.some.call(allboxes, box => box.checked)) {
    allboxes.forEach(box => box.checked = true);
}
```